# How can I use New-ADServiceAccount with a name of more than 19 characters?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, service-accounts

This works:

```
New-ADServiceAccount 1234567890123456789
```

This doesn't:

```
New-ADServiceAccount 12345678901234567890
```

> New-ADServiceAccount : The name provided is not a properly formed account name

I'm trying to replace IIS Application Pool Identities with domain users so I can set directory permissions on a file server. These virtual users take the name of the application pool, which I normally set to the domain for the site, e.g. `com.example.www`
The length of the domain can easily exceed 19 characters. Is there a way to get past this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `-SamAccountName`

From [New-ADServiceAccount](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617211.aspx)

SamAccountName

Specifies the Security Account Manager (SAM) account name of the user, group, computer, or service account. The maximum length of the description is **256 characters**. ***To be compatible with older operating systems, create a SAM account name that is 20 characters or less***. This parameter sets the SAMAccountName for an account object. The LDAP display name (ldapDisplayName) for this property is "sAMAccountName".

The following example shows how to specify this parameter.

```
-SAMAccountName "saradavis"
```

Comment: I had come across this SAM name limit but since it's 20 characters I didn't look into it any further. I guess the 20th character is the `$` being appended?

Comment: Yes, the $ counts as a character as well.

Comment: There appear to be additional length limitations. I've posted my findings on http://serverfault.com/questions/585901/what-do-the-error-messages-and-codes-mean-when-creating-and-installing-managed-s