# What do the error messages and codes mean when creating and installing Managed Service Accounts?

Tags: active-directory, iis, powershell, windows

When using the PowerShell Cmdlets for creating and installing Managed Service Accounts, certain errors can be thrown. What does each error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### New-ADServiceAccount

> The name provided is not a properly formed account name

The SAM account name exceeds the 20 character limit. A `$` is automatically appended when missing and counts towards this limit.

Examples:

```
New-ADServiceAccount abcdefghijklmno -SamAccountName abcdefghijklmnopqrst
New-ADServiceAccount abcdefghijklmnopqrs -SamAccountName abcdefghijklmnopqrst
New-ADServiceAccount abcdefghijklmnopqrst -SamAccountName abcdefghijklmnopqrst
```

### Install-ADServiceAccount

> Cannot install service account. Error Message: 'Unknown error (0xc0000022)'.

Right click on the PowerShell shortcut and choose *Run as Administrator*.

---

> Cannot install service account. Error Message: 'Unknown error (0xc0000106)'.

The SAM account name is within the 20 character limit, but its full name exceeds this limit.

Examples:

```
New-ADServiceAccount abcdefghijklmnopqrst -SamAccountName abcdefghijklmno
New-ADServiceAccount abcdefghijklmnopqrst -SamAccountName abcdefghijklmnopqrs
```

---

> Cannot install service account. Error Message: 'Unknown error (0xc0000017)'.

The full name and the SAM account name are within the 20 character limit, but both of them exceed the NetLogon 15 characters limit.

Examples:

```
New-ADServiceAccount abcdefghijklmnopqrs -SamAccountName abcdefghijklmnopqrs
```

---

> Cannot install service account. Error Message: 'Unknown error (0xc0000225)'.

The full name and the SAM account name are within the 20 character limit, but one of them exceeds the NetLogon 15 character limit.

Examples:

```
New-ADServiceAccount abcdefghijklmno -SamAccountName abcdefghijklmnopqrs
New-ADServiceAccount abcdefghijklmnopqrs -SamAccountName abcdefghijklmno
```

---

<sup>Sources used in addition to own research:</sup>

- <sup>[How can I use New-ADServiceAccount with a name of more than 19 characters?](https://serverfault.com/questions/585818/how-can-i-use-new-adserviceaccount-with-a-name-of-more-than-19-characters)</sup>
- <sup>http://mikefrobbins.com/2011/02/17/managed-service-accounts/</sup>
- <sup>http://www.derekseaman.com/2010/02/server-2008-r2-managed-service-account.html</sup>

Comment: I've tested above findings multiple times, so there shouldn't be any mistake. If you do find a mistake, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours trying to figure out what this message meant:

> Cannot install service account. Error Message: '{Not Enough Quota}
>   Not enough virtual memory or paging file quota is available to complete the specified operation.

```perl
Install-ADServiceAccount (Get-ADServiceAccount msa_test1)

Install-ADServiceAccount : Cannot install service account. Error Message: '{Not Enough Quota}
Not enough virtual memory or paging file quota is available to complete the specified operation.'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-ADServiceAccount (Get-ADServiceAccount msa_test1)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (msa_test1:String) [Install-ADServiceAccount], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InstallADServiceAccount:PerformOperation:InstallServiceAcccountFailure,Microsoft.ActiveD
   irectory.Management.Commands.InstallADServiceAccount
```

[image: PowerShell screenshot]

This error message is completely misleading. The cause of the message was:

The server on which I was executing **Install-ADServiceAccount** already had another MSA installed. This other MSA had a `cn` attribute that did not exactly match the `sAMAccountName` attribute.

Make sure that for all MSA's:

- the MSA `cn` does not end with `$`
- the MSA `cn` matches exactly the `sAMAccountName`

Comment: In my case the **CN** did not have to match the sAMAccountName, but it had to be **15 characters or less**. What was really puzzling was that Install-ADServiceAccount worked on *some* computers, but failed on others, with no obvious configuration differences.

So, this naming scheme: cn = `MyApplication Workstation HQnn`, sAMAccountName = `svc-myappwknn` worked on some but failed on others, while cn = `MyAppWK HQnn`, sAMAccountName = `svc-myappwknn` worked everywhere.

Comment: See also: https://www.derekseaman.com/2010/02/server-2008-r2-managed-service-account.html